# How to filter arrays with empty value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$main = [
  [
    'mykey' => 'mykeyvalue',
    'mykey2' => 'mykey2value',
    'mykey5' => '',
    'mykey4' => '',
    'mykey5' => 'mykey5value',
  ],
  [
    'mykey' => 'mykeyvalue',
    'mykey2' => 'mykey2value',
    'mykey5' => 'mykey3value',
    'mykey4' => 'mykey4value',
    'mykey5' => 'mykey5value',
  ],
  [
    'mykey' => 'mykeyvalue',
    'mykey2' => 'mykey2value',
    'mykey5' => '',
    'mykey4' => '',
    'mykey5' => 'mykey5value',
  ],
];
```

I'm trying to filter the main array so we only get the arrays which have values for all the keys.

So at the end we should only have the 2nd array left.

I can loop through the arrays to check the values are empty and not add it the main array. but I have an array with more than 24K+ results.

So I'm looking for the best way to do this?

Comment: Guys, I would appreciate If you could comment your approach. If you don't want to code for any reason :)

Comment: Well... you'll have to loop over those 24K entries at some point. Then you'll have to check that none of the subvalues are empty (you can stop as soon as one is). The only optimization I can see if to make use of `yield` to prevent allocating another potentially huge array into memory. It depends on what you need to do with the result though.

Comment: One question I would have is, what does that initial array come from? Is it from a database? An API? Can't you filter that stuff there?

Comment: It's from a wordpress database

Comment: I want to import data from wordpress database to my custom web application

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with Wordpress, but I'm guessing there's a way to query that database (is it MySQL? something else?) so that it doesn't return entries you're not interested in to begin with.

Comment: @Jeto Same here, It's a Mysql Database. I'm already selecting the values I need. but the the problem is some records have empty fields.

Comment: Then it's an SQL issue. Try to filter the returned entries so that they don't include those with empty fields. If you run into trouble, you can create a new question (and close this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want with a nested call to [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), removing all subarrays whose length is different after filtering for empty values:

```
$result = array_filter($main, function ($arr) {
    return count($arr) == count(array_filter($arr));
});
print_r($result);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [mykey] => mykeyvalue
            [mykey2] => mykey2value
            [mykey3] => mykey3value
            [mykey4] => mykey4value
            [mykey5] => mykey5value
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Wvgop)

It would be better to try and achieve this in your MySQL query though, perhaps something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE mykey != '' AND mykey2 != '' AND mykey3 != '' AND mykey4 != '' AND mykey5 != ''
```